# the page source code can't be found in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have a page on my website that has been created using the WordPress 'page' format. I want to find the source code of this page which includes HTML and some js files.
The problem is that the code/block editor of this page is empty and I have no clue on how to access the source code.

Below is the code editor that I see without any content although if I open or preview the page I can see that the page works and have access to the scripts that I am not sure where they are.

Any help is really appreciated. I am really stuck on this.

[image]

Comment: Wordpress uses templates. Page are created from that template and directly inserted in the data base. There is no "file" per say. The only thing you can access is the page.php file itself, from your theme folder at the root of the folder.

Comment: In this specific page that I mentioned, I have imported my project that is written in HTML, js, css. Now I cannot find the source code for my project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this page is using custom template in your theme, you can find the name of this template in page atrributes-> Template.
if you want to make some changes in this page(not recomanded if you are not good whith developing wordpress theme) you have to go to your theme directory and find this page template and make change in it.